# Django 2.2 How to disable checkboxes in list view

Tags: django, list, checkbox, view, disable

Django 2.2

I have a list view controlled by admin.py class. No custom template, all default. I can control what fields from the table should be shown in the view with this: 
`fields = ('myfield1','myfield2', ...)`.

Each row in the list table has a checkbox in the first column, the source looks like this:

```
    <td class="action-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="_selected_action" value="123" class="action-select">
    </td>
```

[image]

My questions are:

1. How to disable those checkboxes (preferably, from Django code, without introducing a custom template) ?
2. Can it be done for SOME of the checkboxes (let's say I have a list of pk ids for the rows I don't want to see checkboxes.)

Comment: If you set ```actions = None``` in your ```ModelAdmin``` the check boxes and the action dropdown will be disappear (not disabled). If you really want to disable certain check boxes only I believe you need to add some javascript code.

Comment: @Chris putting `actions = None` in ModelAdmin in `admin.py` has no effect in my Django 2.2. Maybe it needs to be placed inside a specific method inside ModelAdmin class?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-all-actions-for-a-particular-modeladmin) to see where and how to put it

Comment: @Chris No I followed the same doc and got no effect. Must be something specific to  my setup.

Comment: Are you working with django development server?

Comment: @Chris figured out why  `actions = None` had no effect for me when placed inside `ModelAdmin` : my admin's superclass overrides `get_actions`. So, in general to disable the whole thing this will work. So I upvote your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete Items with those CheckBoxes, but if you want to customize your own admin page to override it

You can use this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates

Comment: I know I can delete items using those checkboxes, my question is how to get rid of them. The doc under the link does not tell me.

Comment: you should ovrride the result div in the html page below, with the way on django docs said 
[link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question is 2 years old now, but for the case someone still needs it, the following code works to overwrite the change-list_results.html:

```
    {% load i18n static %}
{% if result_hidden_fields %}
<div class="hiddenfields">{# DIV for HTML validation #}
{% for item in result_hidden_fields %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if results %}
<div class="results">
<table id="result_list">
<thead>
<tr>
{% for header in result_headers %}
   {% if "checkbox" in header.text %}
   {% else %}
     <th scope="col" {{ header.class_attrib }}>

       {% if header.sortable %}
         {% if header.sort_priority > 0 %}
           <div class="sortoptions">
             <a class="sortremove" href="{{ header.url_remove }}" title="{% translate "Remove from sorting" %}"></a>
             {% if num_sorted_fields > 1 %}<span class="sortpriority" title="{% blocktranslate with priority_number=header.sort_priority %}Sorting priority: {{ priority_number }}{% endblocktranslate %}">{{ header.sort_priority }}</span>{% endif %}
             <a href="{{ header.url_toggle }}" class="toggle {% if header.ascending %}ascending{% else %}descending{% endif %}" title="{% translate "Toggle sorting" %}"></a>
           </div>
         {% endif %}
       {% endif %}
       <div class="text">{% if header.sortable %}<a href="{{ header.url_primary }}">{{ header.text|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}<span>{{ header.text|capfirst }}</span>{% endif %}</div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    {% endif %}

</th>{% endfor %}

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for result in results %}

{% if result.form and result.form.non_field_errors %}
    <tr><td colspan="{{ result|length }}">{{ result.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
{% endif %}

<tr>
    {% for item in result %}
        {% if "_selected_action" in item %}
        {% else %}
            {{ item }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

It stops stops the output of the for loops if theres a checkbox in there. --> It just removes the checkboxes.

Comment: How about just hiding the first column using CSS?